# Read JSON data from CSV in Synapse Azure

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a CSV with some columns, one of them with JSON content. Can I query this JSON column with special handling?

An example below:
[ei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeThz.png)

My goal is to run a query ([openrowset documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset)) and get output similar to this.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Valarie Strickland |
| 1 | Mathews Harrison |
| 2 | Cecilia Giles |

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.

My sample data:

[image]

to convert the column with nested `Json` in the form of table. First, I created variable with `nvarchar(max)`. set the select Querys value to it.

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = (SELECT
TOP  100 *
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://dlsg2p.dfs.core.windows.net/fsn2p/jsoncolumn.csv',
FORMAT = 'CSV',
PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
firstrow=3
) AS [result])
```

with below statement checking the value is assigned properly to variable.

```sql
select @json as JSON
```

Using CROSS APPLY for converting Json to table format:

```sql
SELECT b.id as ID ,b.name  as  Name
FROM
OPENJSON(@json)
WITH
(
friends NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS a
CROSS  APPLY
OPENJSON(a.friends)
WITH
(
id INT,
name  VARCHAR(MAX)
) AS b;
```

Execution:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]